# move shape to different directions

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Task:**
I created a shape with 4 buttons, and need it to move to 4 directions depending on the button clicked (pure JS).
This is what I created - check out the snippet.

**Problem**:
Left/Right directions work great, but Up/Down do not. 
Any idea why? Looks like both directions are identical. :/

Thanks a lot for your help, much appreciated!

```js
var shape = document.getElementById("shape"),
  leftBtn = document.getElementById("leftBtn"),
 rightBtn = document.getElementById("rightBtn"),
    upBtn = document.getElementById("upBtn"),
 downBtn  = document.getElementById("downBtn");

 leftBtn.onclick = function(){
  moveLeft();
 }
 rightBtn.onclick = function(){
  moveRight();
 }
 upBtn.onclick = function(){
  moveUp();
 }
 downBtn.onclick = function(){
  moveDown();
 }


function moveLeft() {
    var val = (parseInt(shape.style.left) || 0) - 50;
    shape.style.left = val + "px";
}

function moveUp() {
    var val = (parseInt(shape.style.top) || 0) - 50;
    shape.style.left = val + "px";
}

function moveRight() {
    var val = (parseInt(shape.style.left) || 0) + 50;
    shape.style.left = val + "px";
}

function moveDown() {
    var val = (parseInt(shape.style.top) || 0) + 50;
    shape.style.left = val + "px";
}
```

```css
body{
 background-color: black;
}

#shape{
 background-color: red;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>JavaScript and the Document Object Model</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shape.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
 <div id="shape">
 </div>
 <div id="buttons">
  <button class="button" id="leftBtn" direction="left">left</button>
  <button class="button" id="upBtn" direction="up">up</button>
  <button class="button" id="downBtn" direction="down">down</button>
  <button class="button" id="rightBtn" direction="right">right</button>
 </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="shape.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: to move up/down you have to set something different than **left** ... you are setting left in all the cases

Comment: @TemaniAfif, thanks for your fast reply. Indeed it was the problem.
Now I've noticed that the shape is appearing before the buttons when I move it. 
Any idea what would be the easiest way to fix it? I read about using position: absolute, but then the buttons won't be centered, and I need them to stay centered.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by @Temani, in functions ***moveUp*** and ***moveDown***, changing *shape.style.left* to *shape.style.top* will solve the problem.

```js
var shape = document.getElementById("shape"),
  leftBtn = document.getElementById("leftBtn"),
 rightBtn = document.getElementById("rightBtn"),
    upBtn = document.getElementById("upBtn"),
 downBtn  = document.getElementById("downBtn");

 leftBtn.onclick = function(){
  moveLeft();
 }
 rightBtn.onclick = function(){
  moveRight();
 }
 upBtn.onclick = function(){
  moveUp();
 }
 downBtn.onclick = function(){
  moveDown();
 }


function moveLeft() {
    var val = (parseInt(shape.style.left) || 0) - 50;
    shape.style.left = val + "px";
}

function moveUp() {
    var val = (parseInt(shape.style.top) || 0) - 50;
    shape.style.top = val + "px";
}

function moveRight() {
    var val = (parseInt(shape.style.left) || 0) + 50;
    shape.style.left = val + "px";
}

function moveDown() {
    var val = (parseInt(shape.style.top) || 0) + 50;
    shape.style.top = val + "px";
}
```

```css
body{
 background-color: black;
}

#shape{
 background-color: red;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>JavaScript and the Document Object Model</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shape.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
 <div id="shape">
 </div>
 <div id="buttons">
  <button class="button" id="leftBtn" direction="left">left</button>
  <button class="button" id="upBtn" direction="up">up</button>
  <button class="button" id="downBtn" direction="down">down</button>
  <button class="button" id="rightBtn" direction="right">right</button>
 </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="shape.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```